# JBoss autocommit to Oracle doesnt work always

Tags: oracle, jboss, commit, autocommit

I have a very interesting situation. I am slightly new to JBoss and Oracle, having worked mostly with Weblogic on DB2. That said, what I am trying to do is pretty simple.

I have a local-tx-datasource to an Oracle database. From my Java I code, I invoke datasource.getConnection() after retrieving the datasource using the appropriate JNDI name. The local-tx-datasource declaration in my -ds.xml file does not have any explicit reference to autocommit behaviour.

After getting the connection, I execute a create/update query and I get back the correct update count. Subsequently, for a *short duration*, I am even able to retrieve this record. However, after that the database pretends it never got the record in the first place, and there is nothing at all.

My experience with connections suggests that this happens when the connection does not commit its work, and so only that connection itself will be able to see the data in its transaction. From what I read, JBoss too follows the specification that the Connection returned is an autocommit one. I even verified this from my Java code, and it states the autocommit behaviour is set to true. However, if that was the case, why are my records not getting created / updated?

Following this, I set the Connection's autocommit behaviour to false (again from Java code), and then did the commit explicitly. Since then, there has been no issue.

What could possibly be going wrong? Is my understanding of autocommit here incorrect or does JBoss have some other interpretation of it. Please note, I do not have any transactions at all. These are very simple single record insert queries.

Answer (score 1):

> Please note, I do not have any transactions at all.

Wrong assumption. The local-tx-datasource starts a JTA transaction in your behalf. I'm not sure how the autocommit works in this scenario, but I suppose that autocommit applies only when you are using exclusively JDBC transactions, *not* JTA transactions.

In JTA, if you don't commit a transaction[*], it will be rolled back after the timeout. This explains the scenario that you are experiencing. So, I'd try to either change the local-tx-datasource to no-tx-datasource or to manually commit the transaction.

Note, however, that *not* managing your transactions is a bad thing. Autocommit should always be avoided. There's no better party to determine when to commit than your application. Leaving this responsibility to the driver/container is, IMO, not very responsible :-)

[*] One exception is for operations inside EJBs, whose business methods are "automatically" wrapped in a JTA transaction. So, you don't need to explicitly commit the transaction.

Comment: Could you help me understand as to what you mean by "exclusively" JDBC? 

My code does a Context lookup, gets this local-tx-datasource, and invokes the getConnection() method on it. Result is this Connection. Now I did a UserTransaction.getStatus() to check if it  is in a transaction, and it returned me a Status.STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION

Comment: Your connection is managed by the container, and it's being wrapped in a JTA transaction, not a JDBC transaction. I was actually not expecting to see it reporting "Status.STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION", so, I may be wrong. By "exclusively JDBC transactions" I mean to not use managed connections from the container, to make sure there's no JTA wrapping it. For instance, create a connection like you would in a standalone application (without getting it from the container). Then, see if the behavior persists.